# Generating characters randomly with proper frequencies

Tags: java, android, random, words, letters

I'm making a game where characters randomly appear on the screen, and the user needs to make words using those characters.

Currently, I have a string array with A,E,I,O,U each being there 3 times; and all the remaining letters in the alphabet once each.

I randomly pick a position and print that character from the string array.

Sometimes the letters picked are good, and good words can be made, but sometI me they aren't.

What's the best way about going upon this?

I'm developing it using Java for Android.

Comment: `Sometimes the letters picked are good, and good words can be made` ok what are the good words?meaning full words ? if you want to genarate random meaning full words use word list and randomly pick a word

Comment: Yes I meant full words, sorry. And no, I don't want to generate words . Just alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility to be sure that you get "good letters" every time is if you use a [word list](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/assignments/dictionary.txt), read a random word and shuffle the letters.

Comment: I need a minimum of 35 letters. And then continously need to generate more once the user uses those letters to guess words. I'm looking for a better technique ..